# Can't use sshfs anymore, but I can use ssh

Tags: ssh

I am having trouble mounting a Raspberry Pi4 on my Linux PC.

**Raspberry OS:** `Linux MyDesiredName 4.19.66-v7l+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 12:02:08 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux` / `Rasbian Buster Lite`

**PC OS:** `Linux Mint 19.1`

It stopped working after I've played in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

The current content of `dhcpcd.conf` is:

```
interface wlan0
hostname = MyDesiredName
clientid
persistent
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.20/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

and `wpa_supplicant.conf` contains:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

`ifconfig` gives me this:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe01:bdb6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:01:bd:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16398  bytes 3000472 (2.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15612  bytes 6019341 (5.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It looks good enought, right ?

But, while I can connect to the Raspberry using `ssh pi@192.168.1.20`, I can't do `sudo sshfs pi@192.168.1.20:/ /mnt/RaspberryPi4B/` anymore and it returns: `read: Connection reset by peer`.

This happens when using DHCP IP also.

I've searched online, but I haven't found anything similar, because whenever I type in `sshfs` I only get answers for `ssh`, but in my case `ssh` works and `sshfs` does not.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

The two main reasons for that are your user (client side) is not in fuse group, or your server has not the subsystem enabled. You can check those first:

$ groups

that lists the groups your user belongs to. If you don't see fuse, then do:

$ sudo adduser your_user fuse

Also, check if in /etc/ssh/sshd_config in the raspberry, you have a line like this (uncommented)

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Also make sure that ssh works without warnings of any kind.

Comment: So neither my PC or the Raspberry have a group called fuse. And I am sure I didn't have this group yesterday when sshfs worked.

Comment: From your question, it seems you are doing ssh as a normal user and sshfs as root ('sudo sshfs ...'). You could try to do both as a normal user. Also, you can add -o sshfs_debug to see if there is an error.

Comment: I do it with `sudo` because `fusermount: user has no write access to mountpoint`

Comment: Ok, then also do the ssh with 'sudo ssh' and see if there is a warning. Files like 'known_hosts' are different for different users. If you can do 'sudo ssh ...' and login without interactions or warnings, then -o sshfs_debug is the only way I can think to start debugging the problem.

Comment: Your question could be "can't use sshfs as root, but can use ssh as a normal user". You really have to try doing both things as a normal user (mounting to, say, /home/user/mnt) or do them both as root, to find out what's wrong.

Comment: I can do `sudo ssh` with no warnings or errors. `sudo sshfs` still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you share the output of the command with -o sshfs_debug?